# Unable to see nativescript-vue popup #ref- nativescript-popup plugin

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am trying to implement popover functionality for one of my mobile app where I need popover with an arrow on different players icon and display info. of a player in a popover. for this after some R & D, I found that I can use this plugin [nativescript-popup](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-popup). But I am unable to see a popup when I try to implement it. Here are my codes. It's not giving any error but it's not opening any popup too.

**Home.vue**

```
<template>
    <Page actionBarHidden="true">
       <Button @tap="openPopup" ref="btn" style="width:100;height:40;"/>
    </Page>
</template>
<script>
    import { StackLayout } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/stack-layout';
    import { Label } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/label';
    import { ScrollView } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/scroll-view';
    import { Popup } from 'nativescript-popup';
    import Test from './Test'
    export default {
    components: {
        Test
    },
    data() {
        return {
            popup: Popup
        }
    },
    methods: {
        _showPopup(source, view) {
            this.popup = new Popup({
                height: 30,
                width: 80,
                unit: '%',
                elevation: 10,
                borderRadius: 25
            });
            this.popup.showPopup(source, view).then(data => {
                console.log('aaaa',data);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log('aaaa',error);
            });
        },
        openPopup(arg) {
            //this._showPopup(this.$refs.btn.nativeView, Test);
            const stack = new StackLayout();
            stack.height = '100%';
            const lbl = new Label();
            lbl.text = 'Osei';
            stack.addChild(lbl);
            const sv = new ScrollView();
            sv.content = stack;
            this._showPopup(this.$refs.btn.nativeView, sv);
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Test.vue**

```
<template>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label text="NativeScript is the bomb.com" color="#ff4801" fontSize="22" textWrap="true"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
 </template>
```

Please suggest to me what am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

> Notes: After openPopup() function code update, its working and popup is opening correctly. How can I use it with directly with the Vue component(Test.vue) instead of creating a view inside a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin do not have explicit support for Vue so you can not pass `Test` which I guess a Vue Component, you have to either pass a {N} `View` or native view instance.

**Edit:** You could pragramatically create the instance of Vue component and pass the `nativeView` of root element to your popup.

[Playground Sample](http://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=udD9L3)

Comment: Yes, `Test` is a vue component. So can you please give some idea how can I pass View or native view instance. Its like load component, give ref and then use it like above button ref?

Comment: I have added a note where it's working so can you help with that? @manoj

Comment: Looking little larger in the code but thanks for the help. If any other short way then please write here anytime later.

Comment: It's not really long, hardly 4 more lines from what you had originally. Create instance, mount, and destroy. Nothing more than that.

Comment: yes definately its shorten then before but I was thinking if there is something like inline function from where we can load nativeView by passing component or something like that. For now this is awesome so no issue. :)

Comment: Small issue I am facing in iOS so can you help me? When I open popup at first time there is no issue but after closing when second time I open popup its giving error like `[Error: View already has a parent. View: AbsoluteLayout(220) Parent: Frame<default>]` @Manoj

Comment: It happens only when you try to add View to a parent while it already has one. Please share the Playground sample where the issue can reproduced.

Comment: can you check your Playground sample in iOS. It works in android correctly. same in my implementation. same error `[Error: View already has a parent. View: StackLayout(220) Parent: Frame<default>]`

Comment: I think it's an issue with plugin, it's not updated in a while. Try this - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=udD9L3&v=2